# Search as sentence in phpbb

Tags: php, phpbb

I have a PHPBB. and here it's working as word wise. I have tried magento tutorial, it always separates the words, thus searching for "magento" and "tutorial". is there a possibility to search whole sentence as written?

I need to do the sentence search in my web site. If any one know this, Please help me .

Is there is any settings ? or any code..

Please help me

Comment: Yes that is possible, but i think that is not the question you need do you? you like to know how right? Ever heard of what have you tried: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Yes, i need to integrate this on my site. please help me ..

Comment: Have you googled `Search as sentence in phpbb`? The first hit seems to provide a pretty good overview over what's possible.

Comment: Crap, sorry Pekka! I didn't see these comments. You answered earlier and deserve this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google this particular problem, you will see one of the first results (https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=12772555) that contains the answer to your question. If indeed I am understanding your question, as "word wise" in regards to PHPBB is not very descriptive.